# Webextensions API - Pass data from background-script to devtools panel

Tags: javascript, firefox-addon, firefox-addon-webextensions

I'm trying to pass POST data in Firefox Webextensions API from background script to my custom devtools panels.

I get the POST data like that:

```
browser.webRequest.onBeforeRequest.addListener( 
    getPostData, 
    { urls: ['<all_urls>'], types: ["main_frame"] }, 
    ['requestBody']
);

function getPostData( e )
{
    if( e.method == 'POST' )
    {
        window.postData = e.requestBody.formData;
        // do something...
    }
}
```

Firstly, I tried passing the data using [`sendMessage`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/WebExtensions/API/runtime/sendMessage) but it requires the devtools to be open on page load, while I don't want it like that.

Then, I tried using [`runtime.getBackgroundPage()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/WebExtensions/API/runtime/getBackgroundPage) but I got `getBackgroundPage is not a function` error.

Later, I thought about saving the data using [`Storage`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/WebExtensions/API/storage) but I'm not sure how to do it (never done it before), plus I don't think it's the right way to do that.

Any ideas? I'm pretty stuck, especially because it's my first Webextension.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a nice solution:

In by `background.js` I have this code:

```
var postData = '';

// get POST data for each loaded page
browser.webRequest.onBeforeRequest.addListener(
    getPostData,
    { urls: ['<all_urls>'], types: ['main_frame'] }, 
    ['requestBody']
);

// listen to messages from devtools panel
browser.runtime.onMessage.addListener( ( message, sender, sendResponse ) => {

    switch( message.action )
    {
        // return POST data to devtools panel
        case 'getPostData':
            sendResponse({
                postData: postData
            });
            break;

        default:
            break;
    }

});
```

and in my `devtools.js` I have this code:

```
let sending = browser.runtime.sendMessage({
    action: 'getPostData'
});

sending.then(

    response => {
        console.log( response.postData );
    },

    error => {
        console.error( error );
    }

);
```

Hope it will help someone in the future.